# Twilio Studio Api - how to associate a Flow with a Number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We have a fairly sophisticated Flow (called `Messaging Flow`) set up in Twilio Studio. We are able to assign that Flow to a number's "A MESSAGE COMES IN" action using the Twilio web app:
[image: Set Studio Flow]

How can the same be accomplished using the Twilio Studio REST Api?

I've poured over the docs and I can't find it, and Google is coming up short.

A code sample using the Twilio c#/.Net helper library would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible and can be done via the `incomingPhoneNumbers` Object. You would set the voiceURL property to the "webhook" URL of the studio flow.

```
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var incomingPhoneNumber = IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Update(
            voiceUrl: new Uri("https://www.your-new-voice-url.com/example"),
            pathSid: "PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );

        Console.WriteLine(incomingPhoneNumber.FriendlyName);
    }
}
```

See also [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-update-incomingphonenumber-to-use-a-new-voice-url&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json).

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as the answer, but I wanted to respond to incoming sms messages and so used smsUrl instead of voiceUrl.